# Angular2 - Reactive Forms need to get selected text

Tags: angular

I have a child component that has a form using `FormBuilder` to create my reactive form. I then have a button that emits the `form object` to the parent so that I can display the values on the confirmation page.

I have access to the `form object` and the values by accessing `this.formData = $event.value;`.

On my confirmation page though, I need to show the text (the dropdown label) of what they selected instead of the id based `value`.

I created my form like so:

```
this.transitionForm = this.fb.group({
  changeType: ['', Validators.required],
  hierarchy: ['-1'],
  segment: ['-1'],
  supervisor: ['-1'],
  budgetMarket: ['-1'],
  incentivePlan: ['-1']
});
```

A majority of these fields are dropdown inputs that allow for a single value selection.

Does the form object hold onto this selected text at all?

If not, what would be the best approach to be able to access this information so I can display a readable confirmation page of the data about to be submitted?

Update:

Here is an example of one of my dropdowns in this form:

```
<select name="segment" id="segment" formControlName="segment" class="form-control input-sm">
  <option value="-1" selected="selected">No Segment Change</option>
  <option *ngFor="let s of segments" value="{{ s.SegmentID }}">{{ s.SegmentName }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you share the markup for the dropdown?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz - Updated the question with an example of my HTML dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you only have access to the value that you selected once you've proceeded to the confirmation page, not the actual text.

This leaves you with two options, one more complicated than the other.

You can either write a custom select component which allows you to choose an object rather than a simple value, or you can use the selected value to query for the original `segment` object.

Here's two functions that I use frequently (dependency of `lodash` however but there are pure alternatives you can google also), I've put these in a static `Utils` service that I can pass around in my app without having to inject it:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Injectable()

export Utils {

  static findObjectIndex(list: any[], obj: any, key: string, isCaseSensitive = false): number {

    return _.findIndex(list, (item) => {

      if (!isCaseSensitive) {
        return String(obj[key]).toLowerCase() === String(item[key]).toLowerCase();
      }

      return obj[key] === item[key];
    });
  }

  static findObjectByQuery(list: any[], key: string, query: string, isCaseSensitive = false): any {

    return _.find(list, (item) => {

      if (!isCaseSensitive) {
        return item[key].toLowerCase() === query.toLowerCase();
      }

      return item[key] === query;
    });
  }
}
```

One of them querys the actual object and the other one finds the index of the object. You can choose which one suits you the best.

So for the confirmation page you could simply do get a hold of `segments` and do:

```
// selectedValue would be the selected SegmentID
const originalObject = Utils.findObjectByQuery(this.segments, 'SegmentID', selectedValue);
```

Now you can access anything you want from that object.

I hope this helps.